# Information criterion for cases where $n\gg k$?

Tags: regularization, aic, large-data, bic

I'm looking for an information criterion metric that effectively penalizes the number of parameters ($k$) in cases where we have huge sample sizes. In my particular case my sample size is $\approx80,000.$ I happen to know that the ground truth model has $k=2$ parameters. But if I use Bayesian information Criterion it will incorrectly indicate $k=3$ as the best model. There's some noise which is why the $k=3$ model fits better and given $n\gg k$ it has lower BIC. Due to high $n,$ the $k$ term is negligible. Unfortunately though, I can't model this noise. Instead, an easy solution would be if I could penalize for $k$ more aggressively, ideally with a method with some theoretical support. Any suggestions?

Comment: No matter what, you're going to pick the wrong number of parameters from time-to-time. If all you care about is controlling the number of $k$ picked from a model selection strategy, you should treat it as a multiplicity problem. Use a step-up procedure to control the FDR, that way you can pre-specify the false positive error rate for including too many parameters.

Comment: The derivations of certain optimality properties of AIC or BIC (respectively, efficiency and consistency) do not rule out $n\gg k$, so these methods do have theoretical support. Thus this sounds like a non-problem.